# How do I create a .tgz from Finder using Archive Utility?

Tags: macos, finder, archive, archive-utility

How do I create a `.tgz` from **Finder** using **Archive Utility**? That is, I'd like to right-click on a directory and tar and zip it.

Yes I know how to work with tar from the shell:

```
tar zcvf ../foo.tgz .         # create
tar zxvf foo.tgz -C /bar/qux  # extract
```

But sometimes it would be more convenient to create `.tgz`'s from the Finder.

I've Googled, but my Google-fu is failing.

Comment: Is Archive Utility a must?

Comment: It is my understanding that Archive Utility uses `ditto` and it cannot create a .tgz file.  I'd create an Automator Service with a Run Shell Script _Action_ and then use it to create the .tgz file from Finder.

Comment: No, it's not possible. You can use a 3rd part software, instead.

Comment: Gzip is easy to use from the command-line, which is definitely one of the reasons it's so popular in the Unix world. Just use the best tool for the job! The finder can only create ".zip" files. Anything else, and you're heading to the command line (or some third party app, but the command line is a lot quicker if you know what you're doing).

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/393270/im-trying-to-make-a-service-to-archive-a-folder-using-tgz-i-cant-get-this-to