# I'm trying to make a service to archive a folder using tgz. I can't get this to work

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut, services

I'm trying to learn to build services on my iMac running High Sierra. I open system preferences and then I click on Keyboard. From there I click on the Shortcuts tab. I get the window shown below.

[image]

From this pane, I click on Services on the left and check the box "Archive as tbz" on the right. I then give the shortcut control-command-a as the keyboard shortcut. I then close System Preferences and go to the folder with the folder I want to archive in it. I select the folder I want to archive then right-click on it. A context-menu comes up with Services at the bottom. I click on Services and see my new service at the bottom. I click on it but nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

I've tried closing the System Preferences and going to Finder and run my service from there. No luck. After that, I tried running the service by right-clicking on the folder to archive. No luck. I looked up in Google "how to make a service mac" but no luck. Their method didn't work. Now I'm out of options. I also tried using the key shortcut but that didn't work either. I tried doing the same but used zip instead of tbz but zip didn't work either. Can somebody help me make a keyboard shortcut or a service?

Comment: Where did **Archive as tbz** come from, did you make an **Automator** _Service_ or does that _service_ belong to another application? If you created an **Automator** _Service_, then you should include it in your question. Otherwise, without additional information, this really can't be troubleshot well based solely on what you've provided thus far.

Comment: it appeared under the Services listed.  See my image above.  It was already there, i didn't make it.

Comment: @user3439894 - what else do I need to include to get an answer?  thanks.

Comment: If you didn't make it the where did it come from? It's not an OS default. Is it located in `~/Library/Services`?

Comment: it just showed up. i don't know how to use Automator.

Comment: it must have bben a default on my machine because I wouldn't know how to create it. Plus there are 4 other Archive as lines.

Comment: its not in Library Services.  Maybe I did create it someway but i don't no how to do it!!

Comment: its under files and folders under the Services setting on my machine.  i read that some people had problems running a service but i tried their solution and if didn't work...

Comment: It is not a default macOS Service, what third-party archiving apps do you have installed?

Comment: none that I know of. I've used right-click on a file and selected compress. This creates a zip file.  I'll check to be sure.

Comment: If I managed to create Archive as tgz that still doesn't explain where I got the other four Archive options under services. Archive as 7z, Archive as rar, Archive as tbz and Archive as tgz and Archive as zip.  I do have an app called Entropy which advertises itself as a powerful Archiver for Mac. I've never used it though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following *services* are installed by [**Entropy**](http://www.eigenlogik.com/entropy/):

- **Archive as 7z**
- **Archive as rar**
- **Archive as tbz**
- **Archive as tgz**
- **Archive as zip**

Setting **⇧⌃⌘A** on the **Archive as tgz** *service* does create a **.tgz** *file* in **Finder**; however, I first had to trigger it from the **Services** *menu* in **Finder** before the *keyboard shortcut* worked. This is also where I found the **Entropy** icon on these *services*.

Note: I had to add **⇧** to **⌃⌘A** because in **macOS Catalina** **⌃⌘A** is: **Make Alias**

I also did not have these *services* on a clean built **macOS Catalina** system until after installing **Entropy**, without even running it first, these *services* appeared in: **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **Services**

Comment: Thanks for finding out that info. It still doesn't explain why Ican't create a .tgz file.  I first tried it i Finder/Services then I tried the keyboard shortcut. nothing works.

Comment: @jmh, Have you tried using the **Entropy** _app_ directly, and then try from **Finder**?  maybe using the **app** itself will reset the _services_ it creates. The other option is to run the following _command_ in **Terminal**, which should  rectify any issues with the **Launch Services** _database_: `/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Support/lsregister -kill -r -domain local -domain system -domain user; killall Finder`

Comment: Entropy asks for a registration number but the app is no longer maintained so I can't use that.  I'll try the system command and see if that works.  Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @jmh, If it's asking for a registration number that may be why it doesn't work as its _services_ runs the _application_ in the background.  You should probably delete the _application_ and then run the _command_ from my previous comment to get rid of its non-working _services_.